# Screen becomes unresponsive during game - Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, screen, responsive

I am having trouble with my quiz game - sometimes (not always) after completing a level, the screen darkens and the game becomes unresponsive. I am unable to click anywhere on the screen.

I've been scratching my head about this issue for several weeks now and can't get to the bottom of it.

I'd really appreciate some help/advice on the matter if anyone knows that's wrong. Please see below for the code

Many thanks, Ermes

Xcode, iOS 14

```
2021-08-18 15:41:23.351367+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] FairBid SDK starting with appId 113018, options: <Log level: Verbose, TPN Logging: N, Auto Requests: Y>
2021-08-18 15:41:23.649501+0100 What Team[8408:714325] <Fyber> Log level is set to: 'IALogLevelVerbose'
2021-08-18 15:41:23.666350+0100 What Team[8408:714325] <Fyber> networking client will start a new connection to a resource: //cdn2.inner-active.mobi/ia-sdk-config/config_ios.json;
2021-08-18 15:41:23.672577+0100 What Team[8408:714330] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 89 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 89 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2021-08-18 15:41:23.672617+0100 What Team[8408:714330] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 89 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 89 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2021-08-18 15:41:23.733858+0100 What Team[8408:714327] <Fyber> networking client will start a new connection to a resource: //cdn2.inner-active.mobi/ia-sdk-config/features_config.json;
2021-08-18 15:41:23.734904+0100 What Team[8408:714327] <Fyber> Network status Wifi.
2021-08-18 15:41:23.735146+0100 What Team[8408:714332] <Fyber> First app install, SKAdNetwork IDs will be send again in ad request.
2021-08-18 15:41:23.735539+0100 What Team[8408:714327] <Fyber> No stored remote config
2021-08-18 15:41:23.736516+0100 What Team[8408:714327] <Fyber> ATS settings error with code: 702 did occur
2021-08-18 15:41:23.783592+0100 What Team[8408:714327] <Fyber> networking client will start a new connection to a resource: //sdk-events.inner-active.mobi/Event;
2021-08-18 15:41:23.795926+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] The following SDKs have been detected = unityads,fyber,adcolony,chartboost,admob,applovin,vungle,facebook
2021-08-18 15:41:23.796035+0100 What Team[8408:714068] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C7248CB0-EB34-4C08-BB59-77FC61C9139B/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2021-08-18 15:41:23.796827+0100 What Team[8408:714068] Reachability Flag Status: -R t------ networkStatusForFlags
2021-08-18 15:41:24.014758+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C2.1 23.214.131.65:80 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.015277+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C2.1 23.214.131.65:80 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.027469+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1 2.16.167.171:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.027503+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1 2.16.167.171:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.091985+0100 What Team[8408:714325] <Fyber> Publisher App Store ID set to: 871132014
2021-08-18 15:41:24.120299+0100 What Team[8408:714332] <Fyber> Network reachability did change. Reachability: <IAReachability: 0x28111ce80>
2021-08-18 15:41:24.241919+0100 What Team[8408:714333] <Fyber> networking client will start a new connection to a resource: //cdn2.inner-active.mobi/ia-sdk-config/apps/113018/113018.json;
2021-08-18 15:41:24.250688+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C5.1 2.16.167.171:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.250741+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C5.1 2.16.167.171:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.350417+0100 What Team[8408:714068] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process What Team
2021-08-18 15:41:24.350450+0100 What Team[8408:714068] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
  filterBlacklist =   (
  );
  filterWhitelist =   (
  );
  restrictWeb = 1;
  useContentFilter = 0;
  useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
  whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2021-08-18 15:41:24.350473+0100 What Team[8408:714068] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
  Remove
2021-08-18 15:41:24.483341+0100 What Team[8408:714372] <Fyber> received remote config, parsing...
2021-08-18 15:41:24.571600+0100 What Team[8408:714371] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C4.1 44.194.172.234:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.571631+0100 What Team[8408:714371] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C4.1 44.194.172.234:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.582632+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C6.1 34.249.81.80:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.582658+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C6.1 34.249.81.80:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.587697+0100 What Team[8408:714327] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C3.1 54.210.241.224:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.587717+0100 What Team[8408:714327] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C3.1 54.210.241.224:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-18 15:41:24.623793+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Mediation starting from network
2021-08-18 15:41:24.623800+0100 What Team[8408:714333] [FairBid 3.18.0] Writing mediation configuration to disk
2021-08-18 15:41:24.626338+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] [User session] Restoring data
2021-08-18 15:41:24.626576+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Placement configuration loaded from network successfully
2021-08-18 15:41:24.626813+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] HZFacebookAdapter: ad expiry enabled: 3600.0s.
2021-08-18 15:41:24.627925+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Mediation started successfully.
2021-08-18 15:41:24.627977+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Fyber Marketplace: setGDPRConsent:-1
2021-08-18 15:41:24.628005+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Setup adapter: Fyber Marketplace
2021-08-18 15:41:24.639197+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Facebook: setGDPRConsent:-1
2021-08-18 15:41:24.640046+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Setup adapter: Facebook
2021-08-18 15:41:24.640197+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] AdColony: setGDPRConsent:-1
2021-08-18 15:41:24.640316+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [FairBid 3.18.0] Initializing AdColony with App ID: app981e29968b444858a9 and zoneIDs: {(
  vz166aafb4a6b6442db4,
  vz8ee8148cdd93406ab9
)}
2021-08-18 15:41:24.643100+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [core] isAvailableForServiceType: for com.apple.social.twitter returning NO
2021-08-18 15:41:24.643132+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [core] isAvailableForServiceType: for com.apple.social.facebook returning NO
2021-08-18 15:41:24.643146+0100 What Team[8408:714068] [core] isAvailableForServiceType: for com.apple.social.sinaweibo returning NO
2021-08-18 15:41:24.650528+0100 What Team[8408:714068] AdColony [Info] -[ADCDevice init]_block_invoke Line 640 : ADCNetwork status change: 1
2021-08-18 15:41:24.650949+0100 What Team[8408:714427] AdColony [Info] : AdColony library version: 4.7.0.0 64-bit production
2021-08-18 15:41:24.654170+0100 What Team[8408:714327] [WC] -[WCSession onqueue_handleUpdateSessionState:]_block_invoke dropping as pairingIDs no longer match. pairingID (null), client pairingID: (null)
2021-08-18 15:41:24.659227+0100 What Team[8408:714327] [WC] WCSession is not paired
2021-08-18 15:41:24.687104+0100 What Team[8408:714370] <Fyber> Tracking event:
https://sdk-events.inner-active.mobi/Event
succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a suggestion, but If you are showing an interstitial ad or reward video ad after some levels, that can be it. Some ads can be broken and can be placed on a full screen without visible close button. To check this, if you can reproduce an issue, check it through the view hierarchy in Xcode. To fix this, set timer to force close an ad after some time interval.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes you are correct I am showing interstitials after every 5 levels completed but the issue also appears sometimes after every level completion - the screen darkens and is unresponsive. I have had a look at the view hierarchy but nothing appears off. This also appears but I couldn't add it to the original code block as I ran out of characters on Stackoverflow: Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service - Im not sure if this is relevant at all. Thanks